# Unable to filter using lodash | nuxt

Tags: lodash

How can I filter using lodash, I use the response of an axios call to get the data

```
var wahahaha = _.filter(response.data.results, o => o.date >= this.$data.endofMonth && o.date <= this.$data.startofMonth);
      console.log(wahahaha)
```

How can I query using the function

Comment: What error are you getting? What's in `response.data.results`? What's in `this.$data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have the date ranges swapped:

```
_.filter(response.data.results, o => o.date >= this.$data.startofMonth && o.date <= this.$data.endofMonth)
```

Should be less than end of month and bigger than start of the month no?